# Unity UI document makes other UI document beneath it untouchable

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I have 2 `UI Document` (from the UI Toolkit) in the scene, both of which contains buttons.

I found that if they have the same `Sort Order`, then one of them will not respond to button clicks (or touch, in my case, as I am testing on an iPad).

And if the `Sort Order` is different, the one with a lower number (rendered below the one with a higher number) will not respond to clicks.

I assume this is to prevent when 2 buttons in 2 UI documents happen to overlap and cause confusion. But since I do not have such a design, is there a way to make both UI documents responsive at the same time?

(I am running Unity 2012.3.6f1, built for iOS and tested using iPad Air connected with Unity Remote 5)

[image]